# spring boot oauth2.0 and spring security: How to grant permission(authorities) to user login via facebook or slack

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an auth server built using spring boot oauth2.0 and follows david_syer model.

My auth server does following -

1. Let user login via third party oauth provider like google or let user create his account on our server using username and password and generate token.
2. So, when user uses external oauth like google to login then I simply store the token and pass the same(google) token to my UI app for accessing resource api servers. I have an authentication filter that verifies token and allow api access.
3. When user uses username and password to get token we store user and his permissions and generate a token for him. Now UI uses our auth servers generated token to access resource api servers.

Now my question is

1. Is this the correct way of using token from external api and using the same to access our resource api server?
2. And how do I add authorities to user who are signing up using 3rd party oauth provider since I don't add user entry and authorities for them?

So, spring security which loads user and user authorities (loadUserByUsername() from UserDetailsService) will not have any thing if user came from eternal provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a suggestion for step 2:
After the user uses the google authentication, and gets redirected back to your application page, do the claims transformation on your server and generate your own token issued by the identity server that you have.

The reason is you will be able to provide specific claims and the claims names does not necessarily required to match up.

That way you keep verifying your own token all the time on the client app. So lets say the user uses Facebook instead of Google and even in that scenario as you will assign your own token, you need not to verify the token coming from different third party Identity servers.

That way, your identity server trusts Facebook, Google provided token and your application will trust only your identity server so your app doesn't need to know about what IDP is issuing the token.

And with the approach I suggested above, you will be able to even modify the claims for the user on your own and don't have to depend upon the third party identity server to provide claims.